# Rails query rows with unique column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Booking model and a 'bookings' table with the following columns: id, date, class_id.
Sample data:

- (1, 2021-09-23, 47)
- (2, 2021-09-23, 47)
- (3, 2021-09-22, 23)
- (4, 2021-09-20, 12)
- (5, 2021-09-20, 12)
- (6, 2021-09-20, 47)

A class can take place regularly (e.g. weekly) which can be booked by multiple people on the same day. For example, there are two bookings for the same class on 2021-09-23 and there is another booking for the same class but earlier on 2021-09-20.

How can I query all bookings with only one booking per class and date? For the above sample data I'd like to get:

- (1, 2021-09-23, 47)
- (3, 2021-09-22, 23)
- (4, 2021-09-20, 12)
- (6, 2021-09-20, 47)

bookings = Booking.??

Comment: The expectation for "How can I query all bookings with only one booking per class and date" is incorrect. Only one booking per class & date is just 3 and 6. The other ones have 2 per class/date. Use `group_by`.

Comment: Yes, in the above example, only 3 and 6 are the only classes with only one booking and the other have two bookings. A class on a specific date can have zero, one, or more bookings. My question is how to retrieve exactly one booking of each class and date i.e. skip a booking if already one has been retrieved for the same class and date.